# How many hearings can the House hold before calling for a vote on impeachment?

Tags: united-states, constitution, impeachment

There were [House Intelligence Committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Permanent_Select_Committee_on_Intelligence) impeachment hearings lead by [Adam Schiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Schiff), this week there is another set of hearings lead by [Jerry Nadler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Nadler) for [House judiciary committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_the_Judiciary).
What I want to know is how many hearings can there be before they go for vote on impeachment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**However many the House decides.**

Article 1, Section 2 of the US Constitution describes the makeup and role of the US House of Representatives. [Clause 5 says the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_5:_Speaker_and_other_officers;_Impeachment):

> The House of Representatives shall choose their Speaker and other Officers; and shall have the sole Power of Impeachment.

This means they define their own rules and process.

On October 31st of this year, the House [voted to formalize the impeachment inquiry against Trump](https://www.cbsnews.com/live-news/trump-impeachment-house-resolution-vote-democrats-voted-no-trump-impeachment-rules/), with the following process:

> The resolution approved Thursday authorizes the House Intelligence Committee to hold public hearings and craft a report to be delivered to the Judiciary Committee, where President Trump and his counsel will have the right to cross examine witnesses and review evidence. Republicans can request testimony from witnesses in either committee, subject to approval of the Democratic chairman or a full committee vote.
>
> After receiving the report and holding its own hearings, the Judiciary Committee would be responsible for drafting any eventual articles of impeachment.

You can read the [8-page resolution here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/impeachment-resolution-read-full-text-of-the-house-resolution-authorizing-trump-impeachment-hearings-pdf-download/) if you prefer.

Comment: "This means they define their own rules and process": there's also "Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings."

Answer (score 3):

The Judiciary Committee is responsible for writing the articles of impeachment. After the Committee concludes their hearings, the articles will be written as a resolution. That resolution will be sent to the House floor (the Committee of the Whole) for debate and a vote.

Comment: Although my question is answered by @Rick, I found a beautiful Impeachment Process map on [New York Times][1] site. 


  [1]: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/us/politics/what-is-impeachment-process.html